# web2py - default login form won't to do authentication - can't see any errors?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, web2py

I have followed all steps for setting up web2py authentication form.
Used version of web2py is 2.4.7 stable.

(1) Add Auth to model/db.py

```
from gluon.tools import *
auth = Auth(globals(),db)
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False)
auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = False
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = False
auth.settings.remember_me_form = False
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
auth.settings.hideerror = False
```

(2) Add def user in controller / default.py

```
def user():
    return dict(form=auth())
```

(3) Finally I'm testing my functions with
    @auth.requires_login()

I have inserted user from adminapp in db.auth_user

Login form appears, but I can't login, nor register new user.
No errors, simply text fields are cleared and nothing more happened.

For login_next is appended '#'

```
_next=/init/service/index%3Fservice_code%3Dsfvod#
```

I can't catch any kind of errors or warning.
Please, help if somebody have and idea how to resolve this.

Here is my simple view for user login form /views/default/user.html 
I tried to look into forms.errors and it's empty.

```
{{extend 'login.html'}}
<h2>{{=T( request.args(0).replace('_',' ').capitalize() )}}</h2>
<div id="web2py_user_form">
  {{=form}}
  {{print form.errors}}
</div>
```

I took look at generated Post
Request Body
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------188042046317656
Content-Length: 637
-----------------------------188042046317656
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username" trexxx
-----------------------------188042046317656
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password" greff177
-----------------------------188042046317656
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_next" /init/default/change_language?language=BG
-----------------------------188042046317656
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_formkey" ad38565c-d30a-4f2a-be74-4492e9c19f57
-----------------------------188042046317656
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_formname" login
-----------------------------188042046317656--

For all attempts with auth form - It doesn't authenticate.

I also check my created user/pass with 
auth.login_bare(user_name,user_pass)
result here is OK, user exist and it's correct in table db.auth_user

Comment: Can you confirm that the session cookie is getting sent by the browser? Also, do you have `session.forget()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Great It, thank you Anthony! I really forget about missed  session.forget() and session.clear(). Previously I was trying to do some synchronization within my application. App consists of main category -> subcatergory -